# The meaning of the sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

1) I wish you were there to share the snacks with us.

I have 2 minds to this sentences. I'm not sure how to say it, but I was thinking about the second one below.  Or, the sentence could has both meanings.

1)He brings his snack and comes over to share with us

2)He comes over to share the snack we have.

Answer (score 1):

> I wish you were there to share **the** snacks with us.

Has the meaning: you were in one location which **had snacks** and your friend was in **another location** *(with or without snacks)* and you wanted them to come over to you and **have some of your snacks** but that did not happen

> I wish you were there to share **your** snacks with us.

Has the meaning: you were in one location *(which may or may not have snacks)* and you wanted your **friend with snacks** to join you and **share their snacks** but that did not happen